# Convert seconds (string) to timestamp in Impala

Tags: type-conversion, timestamp, impala, hue

I have 2 columns: `end_time` and `seconds`

`end_time` is stored as a unix_timestamp and seconds is stored as a string.  I need to subtract the `end_time` column from the `seconds` column to get a new column (i.e. `start_time`)

I'm having a hard time with this as I don't think Impala supports `CONVERT()` or `DATEADD()` for me to convert `seconds` to a timestamp, then to subtract it from `end_time`.  Any suggestions on how to do this in Impala?

Example:

```
end_time              seconds
2020-09-02 21:12:34      65
```

Desired outcome:

```
start_time
2020-09-02 21:11:29
```

EDIT
Progress so far:

```
CAST(CONCAT(CAST(from_timestamp(CAST(end_time AS TIMESTAMP),'yyyy-MM-dd') AS STRING), ' ', CAST(to_timestamp(from_timestamp(CAST(seconds AS TIMESTAMP),'HH:mm:ss'),'HH:mm:ss') AS STRING)) as TIMESTAMP) AS updated_time
```

The above gives me the seconds column in a `TIMESTAMP` format with the yyyy-MM-dd of the `end_time`.

How can I now subtract `end_time` and `updated_time` without messing up the dates?

E.g. I don't want to subtract 2021-01-01 from 2021-01-01. I want the time difference to come from the HH:mm:ss, not the yyyy-MM-dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually a quick and simple solution in the end:

```
to_timestamp(end_time, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') end_time
CAST(table.seconds AS INT) sec
date_sub(end_time, INTERVAL sec seconds) start_time
```